# Как выполить scroll при клике на меню?

Tags: javascript

Нужно реализовать прокрутку, при клике на определенный элемент меню с анимацией.
 Скролл будет выполняться к выбраному блоку. Как можно реализовать на чистом JS?

```
<menu>
            <ul class="menu__item">
                <li>Главная</li>
                <li>Инструменты</li>
                <li>Обо мне</li>
                <li>Задать вопрос</li>
                <li>Контакты</li>

            </ul>
        </menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

думаю тему вы уловили

**P.S. поддержка хромает**

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  background: pink;
}

section:nth-child(1) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section id="block1"><a href="#block2">block 2</a></section>
<section id="block2"><a href="#block1">block 1</a></section>
```